# Truncate string to the first n words

Tags: ruby, string

What's the best way to truncate a string to the first n words?

Comment: Are you using just Ruby, or Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
n = 3
str = "your long    long   input string or whatever"
str.split[0...n].join(' ')
 => "your long long"


str.split[0...n] # note that there are three dots, which excludes n
 => ["your", "long", "long"]
```

Comment: `str.split(/\s+/, n+1)[0...n].join(' ')` will improve performance.

Comment: this will get the first 4 words, not 3.

Comment: @ZackXu Make sure you use the `...` range literal, not the `..` one. Three dots excludes the nth value.

Comment: You're right about.  I overlooked.  Mea Cupla.  For exactly this reason, I believe my solution below is better because it's more clear.

Comment: What about: `truncate(my_string, :length => 300, :separator => ' ')` 300 being the number of characters. You won't be able to choose the number of words but that's not so bad!

Comment: shouldn't it be `my_string.truncate(300, separator: ' ')`? http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate

Answer (score 9):

You could do it like this:

```
s     = "what's the best way to truncate a ruby string to the first n words?"
n     = 6
trunc = s[/(\S+\s+){#{n}}/].strip
```

if you don't mind making a copy.

You could also apply [Sawa's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314166/sawa) Improvement (wish I was still a mathematician, that would be a great name for a theorem) by adjusting the whitespace detection:

```
trunc = s[/(\s*\S+){#{n}}/]
```

If you have to deal with an `n` that is greater than the number of words in `s` then you could use this variant:

```
s[/(\S+(\s+)?){,#{n}}/].strip
```

Comment: An improvement: `trunc = s[/(\s*\S+){#{n}}/]`. You don't need `strip`.

Comment: @sawa: You could put that (and your version of the `split` approach) down as an answer, improvements and clarifications of existing answers are worthwhile.

Comment: @GiangNguyen: In that case you could use `s[/(\S+(\s+)?){,#{n}}/].strip`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.split.first(n).join(' ')`
with n being any number.

Contiguous white spaces in the original string are replaced with a single white space in the returned string.

For example, try this in irb:

```
>> a='apple    orange pear banana   pineaple  grapes'
=> "apple    orange pear banana   pineaple  grapes"
>> b=a.split.first(2).join(' ')
=> "apple orange"
```

This syntax is very clear (as it doesn't use regular expression, array slice by index).  If you program in Ruby, you know that clarity is an important stylistic choice.

A shorthand for `join` is `*`
So this syntax `str.split.first(n) * ' '` is equivalent and shorter (more idiomatic, less clear for the uninitiated).

You can also use `take` instead of `first`
so the following would do the same thing

```
a.split.take(2) * ' '
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be following if it's from rails 4.2 (which has truncate_words)

```
string_given.squish.truncate_words(number_given, omission: "")
```