# Displaying Only the first x words of a string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

```
<%= message.content %>
```

I can display a message like this, but in some situations *I would like to display only the first 5 words of the string and then show an ellipsis (...)*

Comment: what's a "word"? is `mother-in-law` one word or three? How about `co-ordinate`?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235762/truncate-string-to-the-first-n-words

Answer (score 28):

In rails `4.2` you can use [truncate_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-truncate_words).

```
'Once upon a time in a world far far away'.truncate_words(4)
=> "Once upon a time..."
```

Answer (score 16):

you can use truncate to limit length of string

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", :length => 17, :separator => ' ')
# => "Once upon a..."
```

with given space separator it won't cut your words.

If you want exactly 5 words you can do something like this

```
class String
  def words_limit(limit)
    string_arr = self.split(' ')
    string_arr.count > limit ? "#{string_arr[0..(limit-1)].join(' ')}..." : self
  end
end
text = "aa bb cc dd ee ff"
p text.words_limit(3)
# => aa bb cc...
```

Answer (score 11):

Try the following:

```
'this is a line of some words'.split[0..3].join(' ')
=> "this is a line"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   # Message helper
   def content_excerpt(c)
     return unlessc
     c.split(" ")[0..4].join + "..."
   end

   # View
   <%= message.content_excerpt %>
```

But the common way is **truncate** method

```
   # Message helper
   def content_excerpt(c)
     return unless c
     truncate(c, :length => 20)
   end
```